# Passing value through .js to php, then using in SQL statement

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql

I have a form, which is supposed to pass three values via .js to a .php page. First two values are for date range and work fine, but I'm lost on the syntax to pass the third value which is a name.

Then assuming I can get that working, the .php page needs to use that name in an SQL statement and again I'm unsure on the syntax, so assuming the value is "name" I have tried various variations on:-

**This is the JS Function, which works ok for the daterange.**

```
    function clickhere()
{
if (checkEmpty("dr_date")) return;
if (checkEmpty("end_date")) return;
if (checkEmpty("name")) return;

var d = convertDate(EL("dr_date").value);
var e = convertDate(EL("end_date").value);
var f = ("name").value;

if (d == null) {
    EL("dr_date").focus();
alert("The date must be in dd/mm/yyyy format.");
return;
}
if (e == null) {
    EL("end_date").focus();
alert("The date must be in dd/mm/yyyy format.");
return;
}

var x = getXmlHttpRequest();
if (x == null) {
    alert("Unable to get XmlHttpRequest");
    return;
}
```

**//syntax problem here?**

```
var u = "outlet-report-dr.php?dr_date=" + d + "&end_date=" + e + "&name=" + f;
```

**//syntax problem here?**

```
x.open("GET", u, false);
x.send();

var t = x.responseText;
if (t != null && t != "") {
    var e = EL("content");
    e.innerHTML = t;
}
```

}

**Then the PHP, first I get the values:-**

```
    $dateStrt = $_GET['dr_date'];
    $dateFin = $_GET['end_date'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
```

**Then the SQL statement:-**

```
    $sql = 'SELECT t.*
      FROM transfer t
     WHERE t.name = $name
       AND t.status <> \'cancel\'
     ORDER BY id DESC';
```

I have all the daterange part working nicely, but not the name, mostly I have just made a mess so far, please assist.

Comment: What kind of syntax error is it? Does your php get's executed? Also, you're concatenate a string "$name" and you try to get the value of a "name" parameter.. That's not going to happen.. It should be like "&name=BlaBlaBla"

Comment: `var u = "outlet-report-dr.php?dr_date=" + d + "&end_date=" + e + "$name"; ` where is $name coming from?

Comment: I have updated the javascript due to the first comment, hopefully the .js now works. The 'name' comes from the form which also gives the other two variables, which I haven't put up. The date range values need to be altered (works fine), but not the name which just needs to be passed through to the .php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your get request should read like this `name = value` where each variable is separated by a `&`

**eg**
`"outlet-report-dr.php?dr_date=something&end_date=something&name=something`

so you will need to change your `var u =` to read somthing like this

`"outlet-report-dr.php?dr_date=" + d + "&end_date=" + e + "&name=" + name`
where `name` is the variable that holds your name value.

**however** if the name value you want is stored in a php varable? try something like this

`"outlet-report-dr.php?dr_date=" + d + "&end_date=" + e + "&name=<?php echo $name;?>";`

**UPDATE**

with you SQL... variables are appended to stings using a `.` in php

**eg** `WHERE t.name = '.$name.'`